# make avro schema from a dataframe - spark - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

i want to write a stream of `dataframes` into `kafka` in `avro` format;

i think that i should publish the `dataframe` schema to `schema registry` as an `avro` schema then write the stream of DF to kafka specifying that schema as an option.

So i need to know how to infer an `avro` schema from the `dataframe` to be able to publish it in the `schema registry`.

if there is another way i would appreciate that

Comment: The binary protocol of Confluent Avro Encoders doesn't include the schema in the Kafka message

Comment: @cricket_007 yah you're right

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.databricks.spark.avro

import java.nio.ByteBuffer

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Fixed
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericData, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.avro.{Schema, SchemaBuilder}
import org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder._
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Type._

import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

/**
 * This object contains method that are used to convert sparkSQL schemas to avro schemas and vice
 * versa.
 */
object SchemaConverters {

  class IncompatibleSchemaException(msg: String, ex: Throwable = null) extends Exception(msg, ex)

  case class SchemaType(dataType: DataType, nullable: Boolean)

  /**
   * This function takes an avro schema and returns a sql schema.
   */
  def toSqlType(avroSchema: Schema): SchemaType = {
    avroSchema.getType match {
      case INT => SchemaType(IntegerType, nullable = false)
      case STRING => SchemaType(StringType, nullable = false)
      case BOOLEAN => SchemaType(BooleanType, nullable = false)
      case BYTES => SchemaType(BinaryType, nullable = false)
      case DOUBLE => SchemaType(DoubleType, nullable = false)
      case FLOAT => SchemaType(FloatType, nullable = false)
      case LONG => SchemaType(LongType, nullable = false)
      case FIXED => SchemaType(BinaryType, nullable = false)
      case ENUM => SchemaType(StringType, nullable = false)

      case RECORD =>
        val fields = avroSchema.getFields.asScala.map { f =>
          val schemaType = toSqlType(f.schema())
          StructField(f.name, schemaType.dataType, schemaType.nullable)
        }

        SchemaType(StructType(fields), nullable = false)

      case ARRAY =>
        val schemaType = toSqlType(avroSchema.getElementType)
        SchemaType(
          ArrayType(schemaType.dataType, containsNull = schemaType.nullable),
          nullable = false)

      case MAP =>
        val schemaType = toSqlType(avroSchema.getValueType)
        SchemaType(
          MapType(StringType, schemaType.dataType, valueContainsNull = schemaType.nullable),
          nullable = false)

      case UNION =>
        if (avroSchema.getTypes.asScala.exists(_.getType == NULL)) {
          // In case of a union with null, eliminate it and make a recursive call
          val remainingUnionTypes = avroSchema.getTypes.asScala.filterNot(_.getType == NULL)
          if (remainingUnionTypes.size == 1) {
            toSqlType(remainingUnionTypes.head).copy(nullable = true)
          } else {
            toSqlType(Schema.createUnion(remainingUnionTypes.asJava)).copy(nullable = true)
          }
        } else avroSchema.getTypes.asScala.map(_.getType) match {
          case Seq(t1) =>
            toSqlType(avroSchema.getTypes.get(0))
          case Seq(t1, t2) if Set(t1, t2) == Set(INT, LONG) =>
            SchemaType(LongType, nullable = false)
          case Seq(t1, t2) if Set(t1, t2) == Set(FLOAT, DOUBLE) =>
            SchemaType(DoubleType, nullable = false)
          case _ =>
            // Convert complex unions to struct types where field names are member0, member1, etc.
            // This is consistent with the behavior when converting between Avro and Parquet.
            val fields = avroSchema.getTypes.asScala.zipWithIndex.map {
              case (s, i) =>
                val schemaType = toSqlType(s)
                // All fields are nullable because only one of them is set at a time
                StructField(s"member$i", schemaType.dataType, nullable = true)
            }

            SchemaType(StructType(fields), nullable = false)
        }

      case other => throw new IncompatibleSchemaException(s"Unsupported type $other")
    }
  }

  /**
   * This function converts sparkSQL StructType into avro schema. This method uses two other
   * converter methods in order to do the conversion.
   */
  def convertStructToAvro[T](
      structType: StructType,
      schemaBuilder: RecordBuilder[T],
      recordNamespace: String): T = {
    val fieldsAssembler: FieldAssembler[T] = schemaBuilder.fields()
    structType.fields.foreach { field =>
      val newField = fieldsAssembler.name(field.name).`type`()

      if (field.nullable) {
        convertFieldTypeToAvro(field.dataType, newField.nullable(), field.name, recordNamespace)
          .noDefault
      } else {
        convertFieldTypeToAvro(field.dataType, newField, field.name, recordNamespace)
          .noDefault
      }
    }
    fieldsAssembler.endRecord()
  }

  /**
   * Returns a converter function to convert row in avro format to GenericRow of catalyst.
   *
   * @param sourceAvroSchema Source schema before conversion inferred from avro file by passed in
   *                       by user.
   * @param targetSqlType Target catalyst sql type after the conversion.
   * @return returns a converter function to convert row in avro format to GenericRow of catalyst.
   */
  private[avro] def createConverterToSQL(
    sourceAvroSchema: Schema,
    targetSqlType: DataType): AnyRef => AnyRef = {

    def createConverter(avroSchema: Schema,
        sqlType: DataType, path: List[String]): AnyRef => AnyRef = {
      val avroType = avroSchema.getType
      (sqlType, avroType) match {
        // Avro strings are in Utf8, so we have to call toString on them
        case (StringType, STRING) | (StringType, ENUM) =>
          (item: AnyRef) => if (item == null) null else item.toString
        // Byte arrays are reused by avro, so we have to make a copy of them.
        case (IntegerType, INT) | (BooleanType, BOOLEAN) | (DoubleType, DOUBLE) |
             (FloatType, FLOAT) | (LongType, LONG) =>
          identity
        case (BinaryType, FIXED) =>
          (item: AnyRef) =>
            if (item == null) {
              null
            } else {
              item.asInstanceOf[Fixed].bytes().clone()
            }
        case (BinaryType, BYTES) =>
          (item: AnyRef) =>
            if (item == null) {
              null
            } else {
              val byteBuffer = item.asInstanceOf[ByteBuffer]
              val bytes = new Array[Byte](byteBuffer.remaining)
              byteBuffer.get(bytes)
              bytes
            }

        case (struct: StructType, RECORD) =>
          val length = struct.fields.length
          val converters = new Array[AnyRef => AnyRef](length)
          val avroFieldIndexes = new Array[Int](length)
          var i = 0
          while (i < length) {
            val sqlField = struct.fields(i)
            val avroField = avroSchema.getField(sqlField.name)
            if (avroField != null) {
              val converter = createConverter(avroField.schema(), sqlField.dataType,
                path :+ sqlField.name)
              converters(i) = converter
              avroFieldIndexes(i) = avroField.pos()
            } else if (!sqlField.nullable) {
              throw new IncompatibleSchemaException(
                s"Cannot find non-nullable field ${sqlField.name} at path ${path.mkString(".")} " +
                  "in Avro schema\n" +
                  s"Source Avro schema: $sourceAvroSchema.\n" +
                  s"Target Catalyst type: $targetSqlType")
            }
            i += 1
          }

          (item: AnyRef) => {
            if (item == null) {
              null
            } else {
              val record = item.asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]

              val result = new Array[Any](length)
              var i = 0
              while (i < converters.length) {
                if (converters(i) != null) {
                  val converter = converters(i)
                  result(i) = converter(record.get(avroFieldIndexes(i)))
                }
                i += 1
              }
              new GenericRow(result)
            }
          }
        case (arrayType: ArrayType, ARRAY) =>
          val elementConverter = createConverter(avroSchema.getElementType, arrayType.elementType,
            path)
          val allowsNull = arrayType.containsNull
          (item: AnyRef) => {
            if (item == null) {
              null
            } else {
              item.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Iterable[AnyRef]].asScala.map { element =>
                if (element == null && !allowsNull) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(s"Array value at path ${path.mkString(".")} is not " +
                    "allowed to be null")
                } else {
                  elementConverter(element)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        case (mapType: MapType, MAP) if mapType.keyType == StringType =>
          val valueConverter = createConverter(avroSchema.getValueType, mapType.valueType, path)
          val allowsNull = mapType.valueContainsNull
          (item: AnyRef) => {
            if (item == null) {
              null
            } else {
              item.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[AnyRef, AnyRef]].asScala.map { x =>
                if (x._2 == null && !allowsNull) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(s"Map value at path ${path.mkString(".")} is not " +
                    "allowed to be null")
                } else {
                  (x._1.toString, valueConverter(x._2))
                }
              }.toMap
            }
          }
        case (sqlType, UNION) =>
          if (avroSchema.getTypes.asScala.exists(_.getType == NULL)) {
            val remainingUnionTypes = avroSchema.getTypes.asScala.filterNot(_.getType == NULL)
            if (remainingUnionTypes.size == 1) {
              createConverter(remainingUnionTypes.head, sqlType, path)
            } else {
              createConverter(Schema.createUnion(remainingUnionTypes.asJava), sqlType, path)
            }
          } else avroSchema.getTypes.asScala.map(_.getType) match {
            case Seq(t1) => createConverter(avroSchema.getTypes.get(0), sqlType, path)
            case Seq(a, b) if Set(a, b) == Set(INT, LONG) && sqlType == LongType =>
              (item: AnyRef) => {
                item match {
                  case null => null
                  case l: java.lang.Long => l
                  case i: java.lang.Integer => new java.lang.Long(i.longValue())
                }
              }
            case Seq(a, b) if Set(a, b) == Set(FLOAT, DOUBLE) && sqlType == DoubleType =>
              (item: AnyRef) => {
                item match {
                  case null => null
                  case d: java.lang.Double => d
                  case f: java.lang.Float => new java.lang.Double(f.doubleValue())
                }
              }
            case other =>
              sqlType match {
                case t: StructType if t.fields.length == avroSchema.getTypes.size =>
                  val fieldConverters = t.fields.zip(avroSchema.getTypes.asScala).map {
                    case (field, schema) =>
                      createConverter(schema, field.dataType, path :+ field.name)
                  }

                  (item: AnyRef) => if (item == null) {
                    null
                  } else {
                    val i = GenericData.get().resolveUnion(avroSchema, item)
                    val converted = new Array[Any](fieldConverters.length)
                    converted(i) = fieldConverters(i)(item)
                    new GenericRow(converted)
                  }
                case _ => throw new IncompatibleSchemaException(
                  s"Cannot convert Avro schema to catalyst type because schema at path " +
                    s"${path.mkString(".")} is not compatible " +
                    s"(avroType = $other, sqlType = $sqlType). \n" +
                    s"Source Avro schema: $sourceAvroSchema.\n" +
                    s"Target Catalyst type: $targetSqlType")
              }
          }
        case (left, right) =>
          throw new IncompatibleSchemaException(
            s"Cannot convert Avro schema to catalyst type because schema at path " +
              s"${path.mkString(".")} is not compatible (avroType = $left, sqlType = $right). \n" +
              s"Source Avro schema: $sourceAvroSchema.\n" +
              s"Target Catalyst type: $targetSqlType")
      }
    }
    createConverter(sourceAvroSchema, targetSqlType, List.empty[String])
  }

  /**
   * This function is used to convert some sparkSQL type to avro type. Note that this function won't
   * be used to construct fields of avro record (convertFieldTypeToAvro is used for that).
   */
  private def convertTypeToAvro[T](
      dataType: DataType,
      schemaBuilder: BaseTypeBuilder[T],
      structName: String,
      recordNamespace: String): T = {
    dataType match {
      case ByteType => schemaBuilder.intType()
      case ShortType => schemaBuilder.intType()
      case IntegerType => schemaBuilder.intType()
      case LongType => schemaBuilder.longType()
      case FloatType => schemaBuilder.floatType()
      case DoubleType => schemaBuilder.doubleType()
      case _: DecimalType => schemaBuilder.stringType()
      case StringType => schemaBuilder.stringType()
      case BinaryType => schemaBuilder.bytesType()
      case BooleanType => schemaBuilder.booleanType()
      case TimestampType => schemaBuilder.longType()
      case DateType => schemaBuilder.longType()

      case ArrayType(elementType, _) =>
        val builder = getSchemaBuilder(dataType.asInstanceOf[ArrayType].containsNull)
        val elementSchema = convertTypeToAvro(elementType, builder, structName, recordNamespace)
        schemaBuilder.array().items(elementSchema)

      case MapType(StringType, valueType, _) =>
        val builder = getSchemaBuilder(dataType.asInstanceOf[MapType].valueContainsNull)
        val valueSchema = convertTypeToAvro(valueType, builder, structName, recordNamespace)
        schemaBuilder.map().values(valueSchema)

      case structType: StructType =>
        convertStructToAvro(
          structType,
          schemaBuilder.record(structName).namespace(recordNamespace),
          recordNamespace)

      case other => throw new IncompatibleSchemaException(s"Unexpected type $dataType.")
    }
  }

  /**
   * This function is used to construct fields of the avro record, where schema of the field is
   * specified by avro representation of dataType. Since builders for record fields are different
   * from those for everything else, we have to use a separate method.
   */
  private def convertFieldTypeToAvro[T](
      dataType: DataType,
      newFieldBuilder: BaseFieldTypeBuilder[T],
      structName: String,
      recordNamespace: String): FieldDefault[T, _] = {
    dataType match {
      case ByteType => newFieldBuilder.intType()
      case ShortType => newFieldBuilder.intType()
      case IntegerType => newFieldBuilder.intType()
      case LongType => newFieldBuilder.longType()
      case FloatType => newFieldBuilder.floatType()
      case DoubleType => newFieldBuilder.doubleType()
      case _: DecimalType => newFieldBuilder.stringType()
      case StringType => newFieldBuilder.stringType()
      case BinaryType => newFieldBuilder.bytesType()
      case BooleanType => newFieldBuilder.booleanType()
      case TimestampType => newFieldBuilder.longType()
      case DateType => newFieldBuilder.longType()

      case ArrayType(elementType, _) =>
        val builder = getSchemaBuilder(dataType.asInstanceOf[ArrayType].containsNull)
        val elementSchema = convertTypeToAvro(elementType, builder, structName, recordNamespace)
        newFieldBuilder.array().items(elementSchema)

      case MapType(StringType, valueType, _) =>
        val builder = getSchemaBuilder(dataType.asInstanceOf[MapType].valueContainsNull)
        val valueSchema = convertTypeToAvro(valueType, builder, structName, recordNamespace)
        newFieldBuilder.map().values(valueSchema)

      case structType: StructType =>
        convertStructToAvro(
          structType,
          newFieldBuilder.record(structName).namespace(recordNamespace),
          recordNamespace)

      case other => throw new IncompatibleSchemaException(s"Unexpected type $dataType.")
    }
  }

  private def getSchemaBuilder(isNullable: Boolean): BaseTypeBuilder[Schema] = {
    if (isNullable) {
      SchemaBuilder.builder().nullable()
    } else {
      SchemaBuilder.builder()
    }
  }
}
```

- https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-3.2/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala
- https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

Comment: What is this? Could you provide at least a little bit of explanation.

Comment: Not seeing how this uses a Schema Registry

Comment: @cricket_007 the code shared here only make an avro schema from DF and doesn't have anything to do with schema registry, it only covers the first step of my question and can be imported from the databrick project, anyway thx

Answer (score 1):

I think that things work like that :

I should prepare the avro schema from the DataFrame and publish that schema into schema registry so that consumers could read the message correctly .

Then encode the DataFrame in avro format.
and finally write the stream of DF like any type of other messages ( without specifying the schema as an option ).

Now i'm implementing this logic, didn't finish it yet.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some points to clarify first:

1. You do not have to send the Avro Schema. If you use [Kafka-Spark Integration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html), it will do it for you. You need to write some configuration such as:

   props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
   props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
   props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
2. You can write a DF directly to Kafka even from queries applied to your Data Frame. You can check the example showed in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) about Creating a Kafka Sink for Streaming Queries.

Comment: actually i'm working on structured streaming, you mean i write `df.writeStream......option("value.serializer","com.databricks.spark.avro")...`

Comment: what you mentioned at the first point works only for spark streaming not structured streaming (that i'm working with )

Comment: From Spark Structured Streaming documentation, deserializers are ignored... Keys and values are always bytes and DataFrame operations need to cast to appropriate types

Comment: @selknam using above configurations the data is not being converted in avro format, it is just being written in json format

Answer (score 0):

val jsonFormatAvroSchema = SchemaConverters.toAvroType(myDf.schema).toString

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).